# Move to Mouse Click in SVG multipath (d3.js)

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js, svg

I need to create a circle and move it to the closest point in an SVG path on mousedown event.

The animation works properly in one path, but when added the other paths the circle stop moving.

Check: http://jsfiddle.net/grf15mqv/

I tried to make paths in one variable but it doesn't work.

The Code:

```js
    var points = [[180,300],[234,335],[288,310],[350,290],[405,300],[430,305],[475,310],[513,300],[550,280]];
    var pointss = [[246,333],[300,370],[350,400]];
    var pointsss = [[400,150],[430,305],[500,433]];
    var width = 1000,height = 600;
    var line = d3.svg.line().interpolate("cardinal");
    var svg = d3.select("#Con").append("svg").attr("width", width).attr("height", height).attr("id", "svgs");
    var path = svg.append("path").datum(points).attr("d", line) //+ svg.append("path").datum(pointss).attr("d", line) + svg.append("path").datum(pointsss).attr("d", line);
    var line = svg.append("line");
    var circle = svg.append("circle").attr("cx", -10).attr("cy", -10).attr("r", 3.5).attr("id", "pointm");
    circle.attr("cx", 180).attr("cy", 300);
    svg.append("rect").attr("width", width).attr("height", height).on("mousedown", mouseclick);
    var lastIndex = 0;
    function mouseclick() {
        let m = d3.mouse(this);
        let p = closestPoint(path.node(), m);
        let forward = true;
        let currentPoint = path.node().getPointAtLength(lastIndex);
        if (p[0] < currentPoint.x) {
            forward = false;
        }
        let pathLength = path.node().getTotalLength();
        getAnimate(pathLength, path, lastIndex, p[0], forward)();
    }
    let timer;
    function getAnimate(pLength, path, currentIndex, finishPos, forward) {
        let animate = function() {
            clearTimeout(timer);
            let scan = path.node().getPointAtLength(currentIndex);
            if (scan.x < finishPos || !forward && scan.x > finishPos) {
                circle.attr("cx", scan.x).attr("cy", scan.y);
            }
            if (forward) {
                currentIndex += 1;
                lastIndex = currentIndex;
                if (scan.x < finishPos) {
                    timer = setTimeout(animate, 10);
                }
            } else {
                currentIndex -= 1;
                lastIndex = currentIndex;
                if (scan.x > finishPos) {
                    timer = setTimeout(animate, 10);
                }
            }
        }
        return animate;
    }
    function closestPoint(pathNode, point) {
        var pathLength = pathNode.getTotalLength(),precision = 8,best, bestLength, bestDistance = Infinity;
        for (var scan, scanLength = 0, scanDistance; scanLength <= pathLength; scanLength += precision) {
            if ((scanDistance = distance2(scan = pathNode.getPointAtLength(scanLength))) < bestDistance) {
                best = scan, bestLength = scanLength, bestDistance = scanDistance;
            }
        }
        precision /= 2;
        while (precision > 0.5) {
            var before, after, beforeLength, afterLength, beforeDistance, afterDistance;
            if ((beforeLength = bestLength - precision) >= 0 && (beforeDistance = distance2(before = pathNode.getPointAtLength(beforeLength))) < bestDistance) {
                best = before, bestLength = beforeLength, bestDistance = beforeDistance;
            } else if ((afterLength = bestLength + precision) <= pathLength && (afterDistance = distance2(after = pathNode.getPointAtLength(afterLength))) < bestDistance) {
                best = after, bestLength = afterLength, bestDistance = afterDistance;
            } else {
                precision /= 2;
            }
        }
        best = [best.x, best.y];
        best.distance = Math.sqrt(bestDistance);
        return best;
        function distance2(p) {
            var dx = p.x - point[0],
                dy = p.y - point[1];
            return dx * dx + dy * dy;
        }
    }
```

```css
* {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }
    #Con {
        border: 1px solid black;
        margin: auto;
        width: 1000px;
        height: 600px;
    }
    path {
        z-index: 1000;
        fill: none;
        stroke: #000;
        stroke-width: 1.5px;
    }
    line {
        fill: none;
        stroke: red;
        stroke-width: 1.5px;
    }
    circle {
        fill: red;
    }
    rect {
        fill: none;
        pointer-events: all;
    }
```

```html
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://mbostock.github.com/d3/d3.js?2.5.0"></script>
    <div id="Con">
        <span>Remove the"//" comment to see the three paths</span>
    </div>
```

Thank you.